# Media Queries are not working with Google Developer Tools

Tags: html, css

I have been struggling for ages trying to figure out what is going on. I have been trying to use media queries on a project but they just aren't working as expected when using google developer tools, I want to use the Toggle device toolbar to resize browsers and style but my media queries don't seem to be working with google developer tools?

Am I right in thinking that max-width works for all widths less than or equal to a number and min-width is all widths greater than or equal to a number?

This is my below code. It is pretty simple. I pretty much just want it to be pink below 425px.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#outer {
  display: table;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

#inner {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

@media (max-width: 425px) {
  #outer {
    background: pink;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: seems to work fine to me... https://jsfiddle.net/g850sdwu/

Comment: I converted your code to a live demo and can't reproduce the problem. When I run the snippet, make it full window, then reduce the size of my window, it turns pink.

Comment: There is a `Full page` link on the right of the Run code snippet buttons, click on it, shrink your browser until you see pink. What is not working? If you are running this for a phone, you need to make sure you have the viewport set properly https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: what devices is `452px?` if you're trying to target mobiles, go for `650px` - other than that your css is actually fine..

Comment: Just a guess: are you zoomed in or out? Then the breakpoint would be at a different physical position.

Comment: hi guys, thank you for the quick replies. I just chose a random number to do a test on. This whole file was just to test media queries. I have been using google developer tools, and when you resize using toggle device toolbar (ctrl + shift + M) It doesn't seem to work. But as some of you say, it is working fine in fiddle and outside of google dev tools. I didn't realise this. Why would it not be working in google dev tools?

Comment: @LukeBennett if this is no longer an issue, please delete the question

Comment: @huangism It is still an issue, as Google devloper tools is actually a really useful way of checking window sizes. Why would media queries not be working correctly with this? Do you know?

Comment: @LukeBennett describe what you are doing to check this? it works as is right now, you are simply not checking it correctly

Comment: @huangism I am using the exact same code as posted, and the toggle device toolbar to resize in google developer tools. I can send a print screen if needed, but do not know how to send one through comments

Comment: @LukeBennett 1 - try it without the chrome tool, use the expand snippet/full page link then reduce browser size. 2 - are you checking this on this page or somewhere else?

Comment: @huangism Yeah this works. But the actual problem is with google developer tools. is this working for you when resizing via the toggle device toolbar?

Comment: @LukeBennett you would have to answer question 2 in my comment for me to answer your question

Comment: @huangism Sorry, I am testing it through a brackets live preview. Where the only thing in the browser is the index.html and media.css that I have posted above

Comment: @LukeBennett if the chrome tool is set to a phone that's small enough or if in responsive mode, the width is below your definition and the page has the proper viewport, it should work. Maybe your test page does not have the meta viewport, post the html page's head tag.

Comment: @Huangism You should post that as an answer. I'm sure you are correct and it is the lack of a meta viewport tag that is the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The media query in your code should work as is. You can see it working if you use the full screen/expand snippet link (resize browser)

If you are not getting it to work in chrome dev tools device view, the number 1 cause is that you are missing meta viewport on your page and the device you are simulating has high pixel ratio( ratio > 1 ). Add the meta viewport and your media query should function as is

Here is an example of the meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```